# Drupal multilingual menu

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have created one menu for all languages and set the items as neutral and added the language translations. But when I add translations, only the *title field* is working and it's not working with others field.

Comment: check this https://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/language/multiple/interface/menu

Answer (score 1):

Install [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module and enable *Menu translation* sub module. Now it allows users to select a translation mode for each menu.
[image]